# Java custom comparator with different sort options

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a an Item class with two properties - id and timestamp. There is a custom comparator class to sort an itemList according to the timestamp.

Is there a way to use the comparator class such that I can specify sort by timestamp or sort by id?

Item class:

```
   public class  Item {

      private Integer id;
      private Date timestamp;

}
```

Comparator :

```
public class ItemComparator implements Comparator<Item>{
  @Override
  public int compare(Item mdi1, Item mdi2) {

    return mdi1.getTimestamp().compareTo(mdi2.getTimestamp());

   }

}
```

Sort code:

```
 Collections.sort(itemList, new ItemComparator());
```

Can I use the same comparator to sort the list by Id too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some modifications, yes.

Add a constructor with an enum argument to define which field to use:

```
public class ItemComparator implements Comparator<Item>{
    public enum Field {
        ID, TIMESTAMP;
    }

    private Field field;

    public ItemComparator(Field field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
```

Then in the compare method, `switch` on the field chosen:

```
@Override
public int compare(Item mdi1, Item mdi2) {
    int comparison = 0;
    switch(field) {
    case TIMESTAMP:
        comparison = mdi1.getTimestamp().compareTo(mdi2.getTimestamp());
    case ID:
        comparison = mdi1.getID() - mdi2.getID();
    }
    return comparison;
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's probably preferable to have your enum extend `Comparator<Item>` directly and use a different `Comparator` for different cases, rather than hacking one `Comparator` to work differently in different cases.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use the same comparator to sort the list by Id too?

Well you could have a constructor parameter to say which property you want to sort by - but personally I'd create a different class for that instead. You can have as many classes implementing `Comparator<Item>` as you like...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/). Then you can sort on any property in your class. You just specify the method name you want to use to get the property to sort. For example:

```
BeanComparator byId = new BeanComparator(Item.class, "getId");
Collections.sort(items, byId);
```

This comparator can be used on any class.

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate comparators. Select which one you want to use in the sort call.